# Remove jdk1.8.0_11 from Home directory

Tags: 14.04

I have install netbeans with jdk.....A folder named netbeans & another folder named jdk1.8.0_11 was created in my home directory...I have uninstalled the netbeans using "sh uninstall.sh" command.
But now how to uninstall jdk and remove the folder?

Answer (score 0):

If JDK is still installed use Synaptic Packet Manager and search for it, if found select Completely remove from system.

Also search for netbeans, though its probably uninstalled.

Now you have to manually delete the folders, reason they still are there is they contains your personal settings and user files.

And while you have Synaptic open look for Residual unused packages, it should be under "Custom Filters" tab in lower left corner. If found you can Completely remove them from your system!

Best of luck

Comment: I have the netbeans with jdk package....Now how to install it so that I can use the jdk from terminal(means I want to compile code using "javac" or "java" command) as well as from netbeans.